# Replace("/", "_"); doesn't work

Tags: c#, replace

Why do none of these seem to work?

```
String.Replace("/", "_");
String.Replace("//", "_");
String.Replace(((char)47).ToString(), "_");
```

The string named "FileName" still says "MyFile 06/06/09"

Comment: Please put some effort into formulating a proper question.

Comment: could you give the full line you are testing please?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Compile error? Not replacing the '/'? Please add some more details.

Comment: Is that a question?
How doesn't it work? What's your input string? What does it return? What did you expect it to return?
A quick test here successfully transformed "/Hey/" into "_Hey_".

Comment: (1) You should really put more effort into your question. (2) This issue (the immutability of strings in c#) has came up quite a number of times already on Stackoverflow, in all sorts of contexts. Did you try to search before asking the question?

Comment: @Juliet - follow the edit trail

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Are you assigning the FileName.Replace to something? It returns the new FileName, it doesn't actually change it.

```
string fileName = FileName.Replace("//", "");
```

Answer (score 10):

You probably want to do this:

```
FileName = FileName.Replace("//", "")...
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
FileName = FileName.Replace( "/", "_" );
```

Notice the assignement to the return value from the Replace function. Replace does not modify the object it is called on.

Answer (score 4):

If that is your actual code then you need to actually assign it back to the value as in...

```
FileName = FileName.Replace("//", ""); 
FileName = FileName.Replace("/", ""); 
FileName = FileName.Replace(((char)47).ToString(), "_");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Filename = FileName.Replace("//", ""); 
Filename = FileName.Replace("/", ""); 
Filename = FileName.Replace(((char)47).ToString(), "_");
```

Answer (score 1):

One more thing I'll add is to check your quote characters...if you paste from Word then you'll end up with the wrong characters.  Of course, you'll get a compile-time error if that's the case...